# Best way to register hotkey dynamically in c#?

Tags: c#, windows, global, hotkeys

i am developing a server-client (client may be multiple ) application, in which server app should have functionality to switch controls over client for i need to define some hotkey like 'Ctrl + 1' for first client, 'Ctrl + 2' for second client and so on. For this i have to register a new hotkey when a new client is connected to the server.

My question :
       Is it possible to register 'Ctrl + 11' as a global hotkey? If yes then how?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4345/NET-system-wide-hotkey-component).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question : Is it possible to register 'Ctrl + 11' as a global hotkey?

No it is not possible. It is not possible because keyboards do not have an <kbd>11</kbd> key. They have keys <kbd>0</kbd> to <kbd>9</kbd> and then if the user needs to input 10, that is done with two key presses, first <kbd>1</kbd> and then <kbd>0</kbd>. You cannot create a global hot key that involves two key presses.

Comment: If someone told you to "press control RM" (like refactor to a method in VS). Would you tell them there is no "RM" key? Or might you assume it is Ctrl+R, Ctrl+M?

Comment: @user for a global hot key you cannot register a key press of that form